# ant.importBuild 'build.xml' failed: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build

Tags: gradle, ant

I've got above failure message when I tried to add an Ant project (named AntDateUtils) as a dependency of a Gradle project.
Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

ant.importBuild '../AntDateUtils/build.xml'
```

and here is the message

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible 
with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

Comment: did you try to execute with option `--warning-mode all` as  suggested in the warning message? it should provide more detail about the deprecation

Comment: Yes, I did. And it is:  error: cannot find symbol AntDateUtils.test(),  symbol: variable AntDateUtils, location: class AntDateUtils